# Find serialization usage

Tags: java, serialization

I'm mantaining some application and I have a class marked as `Serializable` but I suspect that is not being serialized anywhere so the `Serializable` mark is not needed.

What is the best way to be sure of that? It's possible to determine this statically?

Thanks

Comment: Can you remove the `implements Serializable` and see if it compiles and runs? I believe it won't compile if you need it.

Comment: @marcog, That not true, You can compile a code and then still have a runtime error that something can't be serialized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly. Generally, serialization happens when the object is being written to `ObjectOutputStream`, but this most often happen outside of your code (for example in libraries you are using, or in your container). So you have two options:

- dynamically - define this method on your class. Thus you will eventually know if the class is being serialized, without breaking any functionality. But you'd need the system to be running:

  ```
  private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out) {
     out.defaultWriteObject();
     log.info("Object of type " + 
        getClass().getName() + " is being serialized");
     // optionally include a stacktrace here, or use a debugger, to see
     // when exactly it happened
  }
  ```
- try to understand where is your object going. If it transferred over a network, or stored in a temporary storage (session, cache), then it should be Serializable. Otherwise, most probably, not.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's impossible to determine statically, at least very hard -  your object can be a part of non-generic collection, it can be used by reflection, etc.

What you can do is put some logging/debugging code in objects' readResolve() and writeReplace() methods, that are called by jvm when the object is serialized/deserialized.

Comment: using `writeReplace(..)` will override the default serialization behaviour, thus breaking the usage. It would be the same as removing the interface.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure, that it can't be checked statically, except you don't use external libraries at all (which will not result in serious programs)

Perhaps you are using some sort of ORM like Hibernate, which in some cases need to have serializable object, or your object has to be sent through Web-Service or other middleware stacks like Corba where a serialization is done implicitly (when the object is marked as such).

What's the purpose of your class?